# How to assign new data to the variable within variable in R

Tags: r

I have my file names as all.files in working directory. I want to read these files in loop and assign the names as `gsub(".csv","", all.files)` for each file.

```
all.files <- c("harvestA.csv", "harvestB.csv", "harvestC.csv", "harvestD.csv", 
"seedA.csv", "seedB.csv", "seedC.csv", "seedD.csv")
```

I tried something like this below but it won't work. What do I need here?

```
for(i in 1:length(all.files)){
  assign(gsub(".csv","", all.files)[i]) <- read.table(
    all.files[i],
    header = TRUE,
    sep = ","
  )
}
```

Comment: @Justapigeon That won't work. Also you have one extra closing bracket.

Comment: Broken record: "Do not use `assign`. Don't clutter your global environment with objects that conceptually belong together. Use a list."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` is a metacharacter in regex matching any character.  So, we can use `fixed = TRUE` to match the literal dot.  Also, in the OP's code, with the `assign`, there is no need for another assignment operator (`<-`), the second argument in `assign` is `value` and here it is the dataset read with the `read.table`

```
for(i in 1:length(all.files)){
     assign(sub(".csv","", all.files, fixed = TRUE)[i], read.table(
       all.files[i],
        header = TRUE,
        sep = ","
    ))
   }
```

Comment: That works, thank you. BTW, we need one closing bracket before the closing curly bracket.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep them in a named list as it is not a good practice to clutter the environment with lot of global variables

```
list_df <- lapply(all.files, read.csv)
names(list_df) <- sub("\\.csv", "", all.files)
```

You can always extract individual dataframes as `list_df[["harvestA"]]`, `list_df[["harvestB"]]` etc.

If you still need them as separate dataframes

```
list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `strsplit`

```
for (i in seq_along(all.files)) {
      assign(x = strsplit(allfiles[i],"\\.")[[1]][1], 
             value = read.csv(all.files[i]),
             pos = .GlobalEnv)
    }
```